# creating animation in WP7 for audio recording

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I m doing some audio recording in my WP7 application. I want to show some basic animation to the user like one very small red button blinking or else three small buttons blinking one after the other till the recording is complete. Please let me know any idea on how to achieve this animation in WP7. I m not sure how to use the expression blend tools for animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is the exact stuff you'll want Expression Blend for to create Storyboard animations because it makes it so much easier. However basically you just want to put some objects (in this case we'll use ellipses as an example) on your design surface, then set their opacities to the keyframes of a storyboard. I went ahead and made you a quick example of exactly what I think you're asking for you could customize to suit your needs. Hope it helps, otherwise you might want to read or watch a quick tutorial on Storyboard animations, and know what ControlStoryboardAction & EventTriggers do for ya. I wont say its perfect but it will serve as a good start. :)

```
 <Style x:Key="QuickAnimatedDots" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource
PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource
PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource
PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource
PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource
PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Transparent" Width="55" Height="25">
                                                <Grid.Resources>
                                                        <Storyboard x:Name="QuickNDirtyAnimatedDots" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4">
                                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0"/>
                                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1">
                                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0"/>
                                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
                                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0"/>
                                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                </Grid.Resources>
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" SourceName="grid">
                                                                        <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource
QuickNDirtyAnimatedDots}"/>
                                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="15"
Height="15" Stroke="#FFF50606" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF970404" Offset="0.809"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDE0707" Offset="0.568"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFDB4B4" Offset="0"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0808" Offset="0.436"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF7A0303" Offset="0.988"/>
                                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                                                        </Ellipse>
                                                        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="15"
Height="15" Stroke="#FFF50606" Margin="5,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF970404" Offset="0.809"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDE0707" Offset="0.568"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFDB4B4" Offset="0"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0808" Offset="0.436"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF7A0303" Offset="0.988"/>
                                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                                                        </Ellipse>
                                                        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="15"
Height="15" Stroke="#FFF50606" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF970404" Offset="0.809"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDE0707" Offset="0.568"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFDB4B4" Offset="0"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0808" Offset="0.436"/>
                                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF7A0303" Offset="0.988"/>
                                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                                                        </Ellipse>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Ah I did do a speed read through and confused WP7 and WPF but at the same time, you can still trigger storyboards on a WP7, just would require a bit of tweaking. I use them. Thanks though kP, always a pleasure :)

Comment: thanks chris for your answer cant figure out how to add this code to my WP7 app. I cant create an new app in blend with window resources . I m always getting phone application page resources any idea. Please help me out as I m very new to expression blend

Comment: Ok so check the xaml I replaced above. Just add it to your resource dictionary like any other control template and call it to a button with the <Button Style="{StaticResource QuickAnimatedDots}"...> tag. Of course you could change it to a different control targettype or whatever you like and play with time delay etc to make it what you want, then just put it at visibility collapse when its not being needed. Should work fine for ya, hope this makes it easier and helpful! Cheers!

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I used the code in my WP7 app and its working fine. But I want to start the animation only when the record button is clicked. So I tried the following

Comment: Sorry mate but I can't see anything after "So I tried the following" but starting the animation only requires it being made visible since the event trigger is set to an on load event. So in other words if its made collapsed by default, and onclick of your recording it's made visible, the animation should start. Good luck!